# CSS selector unable to locate element that exist with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm scrapping some profiles on linkedin and my code had been working until today. I found a random user profile and suddenly it stopped working. I checked the code and the html has not changed.

I'm getting a person's education section and capturing the college and degree that the person has. I do this through this:

```
for education in edu:
      ed['College'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=\'mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold\'] span').text]
      ed['Degree'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=\'t-14 t-normal\'] span').text]
```

As I mentioned the code had been working just fine until today and I'm not sure why it stopped working.

The html for this portion is as follows:

```
<span class="t-14 t-normal">
              <span aria-hidden="true"><!---->Bachelor's degree, Human Resources Development<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->Bachelor's degree, Human Resources Development<!----></span>
            </span>
```

The college portion works but it breaks when it tries to get the degree portion.

I attempted to include an implicit wait in case it did not have enough time to load before it was trying to capture but it did not work.

What broke this code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the profile did not have a degree for one of their college section and it was complaining because of that. In order to fix that I used javascript command to avoid error.

That code now looks like this:

```
for education in edu:
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    ed['College'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=\'mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold\'] span').text]
    ed['Degree'] += [driver.execute_script(
        'return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class=\'t-14 t-normal\']:nth-child(2) span")?.innerText',
        education)]
```

Comment: TBH If you can do that you might as well switch to puppeteer.